# How to convert Fetch to Axios and Class component to Functional component?

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch, react-functional-component

How to convert Fetch to Axios and Class component to Functional component?

I want to learn to implement Infinite-Scrolling using functional component and axios in React native, but it is difficult to apply because the reference document is composed of class component and fetch.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image,
  Text,
    FlatList, // here
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    data: [],
    page: 1 // here
  }

  _renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <View style={{borderBottomWidth:1, marginTop: 20}}>
      <Image source={{ uri: item.url }} style={{ height: 200}} />
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text>{item.id}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  
  _getData = () => {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=10&_page=' + this.state.page;
    fetch(url)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ 
          data: this.state.data.concat(data),
          page: this.state.page + 1
        })
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getData();
  }

  // here
  _handleLoadMore = () => {
    this._getData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList 
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        onEndReached={this._handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={1}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When converting from a class to a function component, there are a few steps which are relevant here:

- replace lifecycle events like `componentDidMount` with `useEffect`.
- replace component state with one or many `useState` hooks.
- convert class methods to plain functions.
- remove all references to `this`.
- delete `render()` and just `return` the JSX directly.

The methods `_renderItem`, `_getData`, and `_handleLoadMore` are basically unchanged.  They just become `const` variables instead of class properties.

Here's the straight conversion from class to function component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image,
  Text,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
      <Image source={{ uri: item.url }} style={{ height: 200 }} />
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text>{item.id}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  const _getData = () => {
    const url =
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=10&_page=' + page;
    fetch(url)
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.concat(data));
        setPage(page + 1);
      });
  };

  const _handleLoadMore = () => {
    _getData();
  };

  // useEffect with an empty dependency array replaces componentDidMount()
  useEffect(() => _getData(), []);

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={_renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      onEndReached={_handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={1}
    />
  );
}
```

Here it is with `axios` and with a few other improvements.  I noticed that the end reached function was being called upon reaching the end of the initial zero-length list causing the first page to be fetched twice.  So actually the `componentDidMount` is not needed.  I changed from `.then()` to `async`/`await`, but that doesn't matter.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const _renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
      <Image source={{ uri: item.url }} style={{ height: 200 }} />
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text>{item.id}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  const _getData = async () => {
    const url =
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=10&_page=' + page;
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    setData(data.concat(res.data));
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  const _handleLoadMore = () => {
    _getData();
  };

  // useEffect with an empty dependency array replaces componentDidMount()
  useEffect(() => {
    // put async functions inside curly braces to that you aren't returing the Promise
    _getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={_renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      onEndReached={_handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={1}
    />
  );
}
```

[Expo Link](https://snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/infinite-scroll-api-axios) -- It works on my device, but the infinite scroll doesn't seem to work in the web preview.

There are additional more "advanced" improvements that you can make:

- set state with a callback of previous state to ensure that values are always correct. `setPage(current => current + 1)` `setData(current => current.concat(res.data))`
- memoization with `useCallback` so that functions like `_renderItem` maintain a constant reference across re-renders.
- exhaustive `useEffect` dependencies (requires memoization).